# GitHub API not parsing

Tags: ios, json, parsing, github-api, codable

This is a part of the JSON i am getting from Github in response to a request

```
{
  "total_count": 1657,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 68911683,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk2ODkxMTY4Mw==",
      "name": "tetros",
      "full_name": "daniel-e/tetros",
      "private": false,
      "html_url": "https://github.com/daniel-e/tetros",
      "description": "Tetris that fits into the boot sector.",
      "size": 171,
      "stargazers_count": 677,
      "watchers_count": 677,
      "language": "Assembly",
    }
    ]
}
```

This is my Model

```
struct RepoGroup:Codable {

    var items:[Repo]

}

struct Repo: Codable {

var fullName:String
var stars:Int
var watchers:Int

init(url:String,star:Int,watcher:Int) {
    fullName = url
    stars = star
    watchers = watcher
}

enum MyStructKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case fullName = "full_name"
    case stars = "stargazers_count"
    case watchers = "watchers_count"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MyStructKeys.self)
    let fullName: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fullName)
    let stars: Int = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .stars)
    let watchers: Int = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .watchers)

    self.init(url: fullName, star: stars, watcher: watchers)
}

}
```

So far so good. But as soon as i add `description:String` field in my model, the JSON decoder inexplicably fails to parse.

Here is my parser

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(RepoGroup.self, from: dataResponse)
```

I am struggling to understand what is so special about the description field. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description appears to be an optional field in the GitHub API, and when a repo doesn't define a description, it is coming back as a `null`. This means you need to make your description field a `String?` and switch to using `decodeIfPresent` to account for the fact that it is optional.

Comment: Wow finally it works. Thanks a lot. Could i ask you for a favour. I was going through all the gihub api but could not find this information that description could be null, Could you please give me the link for this information. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up needing to use their search API (https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) on a repo with an empty description to find out the problem. Their repo API documentation gives sample output, but their answers don’t take into account corner cases like that. 

The good news, usually when you add a new field in your parsing, and it stops working, it’s either data format, or an optional field you’re assuming is required, so those are the first two things I usually try out.

Comment: Such a shame so many hours wasted due to insufficient information. Anyways really   grateful for this help otherwise don't know how many more hours would have been  wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems off about that particular JSON to not work for description. Haven't tested this, but this is what your code looks like?

```
struct RepoGroup:Codable {

    var items:[Repo]

}

struct Repo: Codable {

var fullName:String
var stars:Int
var watchers:Int
var description:String

init(url:String,star:Int,watcher:Int,description:String) {
    fullName = url
    stars = star
    watchers = watcher
    description = description
}

enum MyStructKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case fullName = "full_name"
    case stars = "stargazers_count"
    case watchers = "watchers_count"
    case description = "description"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MyStructKeys.self)
    let fullName: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fullName)
    let stars: Int = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .stars)
    let watchers: Int = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .watchers)
    let description: String = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)

    self.init(url: fullName, star: stars, watcher: watchers, description: description)
}

}
```

Comment: Already tried using this exact same code. Every property seem to be able to be parsed correctly except description and this is driving me crazy for the past few hours.

Comment: Yeah, that's really weird. I'm not sure if it would fix it, but what about changing the "description" variable name to something like "desc".. Does it matter? Just spit balling since nothing looks out of the ordinary to me.